# Character/Inventory/Equipment DB structure - Django/SQLite

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm teaching myself django and wanted a simple set up for users to have multiple characters, each with their own equipment/inventory. I've never worked with databases so getting the relations correct is something I need help/guidance on.

My thinking:
A `User` can have multiple `UserCharacters`, which each have reference to a base `Character` instance, along with some `BaseAttributes` and `AttributeModifiers`. Each `UserCharacter` also has an inventory made of of `InventoryItems` which, like `UserCharacters`, reference an `Item` instance, and have `BaseAttributes` and `AttributeModifiers`.

I was wondering if it was wise/possible to re-use identical `InventoryItems` (and `BaseAttributes`, `AttributeModifiers`, etc) across `UserCharacters`. IE if two `UserCharacters` each have an inventory that contains a "Sword" `Item` with identical stats, could I assign that Sword `InventoryItem` to both `UserCharacters` inventories and then just create a new instance if one of them changes?

The models I have right now (please scroll, as some of this is getting hidden)

```
========================================
| User
|---
| username
========================================

========================================
| AttributedObject
|---
| attributes
| modifiers
========================================

========================================
| Attribute
|---
| name
| description
========================================

========================================    
| BaseAttribute
|---
| object >- ForeignKey(AttributedObject.id), related_name='attributes'
| attribute >- ForeignKey(Attribute.id)
| value
========================================

========================================
| AttributeModifier
|---
| object >- ForeignKey(AttributedObject.id), related_name='modifiers'
| attribute >- ForeignKey(Attribute.id)
| value
| method
| duration
========================================

========================================
| Item(AttributedObject)
|---
| name
| stack_size
========================================

========================================
| Character(AttributedObject)
|---
| name
| description
========================================

========================================
| UserCharacter(AttributedObject)
|---
| user >- ForeignKey(User.id), related_name='characters'
| character >- ForeignKey(Character.id)
| inventory
========================================

========================================
| InventoryItem(AttributedObject)
|---
| user_character >- ForeignKey(UserCharacter), related_name='inventory'
| item >- ForeignKey(Item)
| amount
========================================
```

There isn't much code right now as I don't want to go through the trouble setting this up just to change it after figuring out a correct route, but I will try to provide anything necessary for a more helpful answer.

Also, any recommendations on the existing structure I outlined would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In SQlite3, I would just recommend having a separate table for `InventoryItem`s, and putting an `InventoryItem`'s unique id in an entry for the `UserCharacter`'s inventory.

On a separate note, depending on how many `InventoryItem`s a character can carry, you might want to also create a separate table for all `InventoryItem`s held by all characters, with fields to denote the id of the `InventoryItem` and `UserCharacter`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually have a table like that set up, though you'll need to scroll in the formatted code section since it's getting cut off.

Comment: If there are going to be any different between different `InventoryItem`s among different `UserCharacter`s, ie maybe one character has the same sword as another but modified it to output more damage, then I would recommend two things: change the reference of the item in the character's inventory to reference a different item if there are a known and finite amount of item variations. If that doesn't work, you can try adding extra fields to the `InventoryItem` table that account for possible item modifications. Does this answer your question?